# Getting syntax error in query using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while executing my sql query.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's%' ORDER BY gallery_id DESC' at line 1`

I am explaining my query below.

```
$searchKey="Celli's"
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
$query = "SELECT * from db_gallery WHERE description LIKE '" . $keyword . "'
          ORDER BY gallery_id DESC ";
```

Here I need to search value but when `'s` is coming with any keyword its throwing error. Please help me.

Comment: In your search string there is `'` so when ever you are trying to execute your query it will return syntax error. because this will break your query. so use `mysql_real_escape_string` with your keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `'` contained in `$searchKey`, so there are actually three `'`s in your query: not corresponding!

You should escape first (both are okay):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$searchKey = $mysqli->real_escape_string($searchKey);

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$searchKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $searchKey);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @subhra and if you are using other ways to connect db and send queries, use its method of escaping the string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the **'** character like:

```
searchKey = 'something'
searchKey = searchKey.replace("'", "\\'");
```

now use searchKey in your query.

Or use some query escape string function to escape these characters.

Comment: The search keyword value may be like `celli or celli's` this.

Answer (score 0):

Change $searchKey="Celli's"

with $searchKey="Celli\'s" (You are missing a backslash)

Answer (score 0):

There is a ' contained in $searchKey so you need to escape it,use mysqli escape string:

**Note:** `mysqli_real_escape_string` expects first argument as connection

```
$keyword="Celli's"
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");//procedural
$searchKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $keyword);

echo $searchKey;// use this in sql
```

if you are using object type then:

```
    $con=new mysqli("localhost","root","root","test");//procedural
    $searchKey = $mysqli->real_escape_string($keyword);
    echo $searchKey;// use this in sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchKey="Celli\'s"
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
$query = "SELECT * from db_gallery WHERE description LIKE '" . $keyword . "'
          ORDER BY gallery_id DESC ";
```

Simple mistake try this.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below query.

```
$keyword = '%Celli''s%';
"SELECT * from db_gallery WHERE description LIKE ".$keyword." ORDER BY gallery_id DESC";
```